# Rails friendly id with non-Latin characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, arabic, hebrew, friendly-id

I have a model which I use its friendly id as slug:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :slug_candidates, :use => :scoped, :scope => :account

def slug_candidates
  :title_and_sequence
end


def title_and_sequence
  slug = normalize_friendly_id(title)
      :
  # some login to add sequence in case of collision
      :
end
```

My problem is that when I use non-Latin chars (Arab, Hebrew,...) I get an empty slug.
Is there any nice-and-easy solution?

---

## UPDATE

Just to make my question clear, I would like to have the same behaviour as WordPress, which means:

```
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Title              | url                                                |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Hello World!!      | /hello-world                                       |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Helló Világ        | /hello-vilag                                       |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| שלום עולם          | /%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| مرحبا              | %D9%85%D8%B1%D8%AD%D8%A8%D8%A7                     |
+--------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

(both Arabic and Hebrew are translated in modern browsers to original and readable characters).

Comment: You need to use something to transliterate the non-latin alphabets to latin. Did you take a look at `String#parameterize` (it's added by Rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @michalszyndel notes and ideas I managed to get the following solution, hope it will be helpful for more people.

**First, how to make non-unicode chars in slug:**

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :slug_candidates, :use => :scoped, :scope => :account

def slug_candidates
  :title_and_sequence
end

def title_and_sequence
  # This line switch all special chars to its unicode
  title_unicode = heb_to_unicode(title)

  slug = normalize_friendly_id(title_unicode)
      :
  # some login to add sequence in case of collision
  # and whatever you need from your slug
      :
end

def heb_to_unicode(str)
  heb_chars = 'אבגדהוזחטיכךלמםנןסעפףצץקרשת'
  heb_map = {}
  heb_chars.split("").each {|c| heb_map.merge!({c => URI::encode(c)})}
  # This regex replace all Hebrew letters to their unicode representation
  heb_re = Regexp.new(heb_map.keys.map { |x| Regexp.escape(x) }.join('|'))

  return str.gsub(heb_re, heb_map)
end
```

I also needed to modify `normalize_friendly_id` in order to avoid it to get rid of the `%`.
I simply took the code of [parameterize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/parameterize) method and added `%` to the regex:

```
def normalize_friendly_id(string)
  # replace accented chars with their ascii equivalents
  parameterized_string = I18n.transliterate(string)

  sep = '-'

  # Turn unwanted chars into the separator
  # We permit % in order to allow unicode in slug
  parameterized_string.gsub!(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-_\%]+/, sep)
  unless sep.nil? || sep.empty?
    re_sep = Regexp.escape(sep)
    # No more than one of the separator in a row.
    parameterized_string.gsub!(/#{re_sep}{2,}/, sep)
    # Remove leading/trailing separator.
    parameterized_string.gsub!(/^#{re_sep}|#{re_sep}$/, '')
  end
  parameterized_string.downcase
end
```

Now if I save a model with the title `שלום` its slug is saved as `%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D`.
In order to find the instance using the `friendly` method I need to do the following:

```
id = URI::encode(params[:id]).downcase
Page.friendly.find(id)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a Rails API method for that [`transliterate`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/transliterate)

Example use:

```
transliterate('ÃrÃ¸skÃ¸bing')
# => "AEroskobing"
```

By default it only supports latin-based languages and Russian but you should be able to find rules for other alphabets as well (as explained in the linked doc)

**EDIT**
To achieve the same behaviour as wordpress you can simply use url encoding, as in example below

```
URI::encode('שלום') => "%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D"
```

Comment: Please check my update. If I understand your idea, I need to translate each character to its unicode using `transliterate`?

Comment: @guyaloni Well, to do what you wrote in an update you can just use url encode like this `URI::encode('שלום')
=> "%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D"`, no transliterate required. Transliterate would allow you to replace other alphabet chars with latin chars.

Comment: That's right... so again, in simple words - how can I achieve the same behavior like WordPress?

Comment: Not completely... wordpress DO convert Latin characters with accent into non-accent chars (`Helló Világ -> /hello-vilag`), which in this case won't happen.

Comment: well, I think you should look into wordpress code then, but I think it's going to be hacky... looks like they are transliterating extended ascii but encoding utf8

Comment: So I rolled up my sleeves and dug into this fine piece of code. Title to slug conversion seems to be happening here, I looked at the code and well... have fun! https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/formatting.php#L1515

Comment: Here you go http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/FriendlyId/Slugged.html#normalize_friendly_id-instance_method If you redefine this method in your model and don't call super inside it will return any slug you want :)